# Keras Conv 3d Error layer conv3d is incompatible with the layer

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to create a convolutional neural network for mnist handwritting dataset and I'm having a problem with my code :

```
initWeight = initializers.RandomNormal(stddev = 0.0025)

initBias = initializers.Constant(0.1)

model = models.Sequential()

model.add(layers.Conv2D(25, (12,12), activation='relu', strides = 2,
                        padding = "valid", input_shape=(28, 28, 1),
                        kernel_initializer= initWeight,
                        bias_initializer=initBias))

model.add(layers.Conv3D(64, (5,5,25), activation='relu',
                        padding = "same",
                        kernel_initializer= initWeight,
                        bias_initializer=initBias))

model.summary()
```

and I'm getting the error

```
ValueError: Input 0 of layer conv3d is incompatible with the layer: : expected min_ndim=5, found ndim=4. Full shape received: [None, 9, 9, 25]
```

But I'm not entirely sure what the problem is, I want to create a layer after the 2d one which creates 64 filters using a kernal size of 5x5x25.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got what you were trying to do. Assuming the tensors are in `channel last` format. For a `Conv2D` layer the acceptable input is 4 dimensional, i.e, `(batch_size, width, height, number_of_channels)`. So similarly for `Conv3D` the layer will accept a 5 dimensional tensor.

Here from the first `Conv2D` layer you are getting an output of shape `(batch_size, 9, 9, 25)`. `batch_size` will be shown as `None` as it still doesn't know the batch size until we give it data. Or, in other words it can take any batch sizes.

But anyway, the main point is that, although the `Conv2D` is returning output having `25` channels, you need not explicitly mention each of the **filters'** number of channels in the next layer (probably this is why you mistakenly used 3D convolution). But the reality is that, the framework is already designed to take the exact number of channels (25) for each of the filters (in the next layer) such that they can match with their input's (output of the first Conv2D) number of channels' count.

So replace the `Conv3D` with the following `Conv2D`:

```
model.add(layers.Conv2D(64, (5,5), activation='relu',
                        padding = "same",
                        kernel_initializer= initWeight,
                        bias_initializer=initBias))
```

This will actually take `64` filters and each of them are `(5, 5, 25)` in shape. Although we didn't mention `25` but it will automatically do so, to match the channel-count of its input.

Comment: Thank you very much - that makes a lot of sense and a very helpful answer (sorry am new to doing ML in python)